# Mongo: document from ReferenceField was deleted - how to handle DoesNotExist gracefully?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Say I have a model like this one:

```
class Event(Document):
    type = StringField(required=True)
    party= ReferenceField(Party, required=True, null=False)
```

that I save instances of like this:

```
some_party = Party.objects.first()

Event(
    type='some event type',
    party=some_party,
).save()
```

Now if at some point in time I do `some_party.delete()` and try to to retrieve any event that has a reference to `some_party` in its "party" field, I will get an error like this one:

```
mongoengine.errors.DoesNotExist: Trying to dereference unknown document DBRef('party', ObjectId('62286f65088c4f1d723574c6'))
```

What would be a neat way to handle such situations? Should I leave it like this and maybe pepper my code with try/except blocks to check for `DoesNotExist`, or should I maybe somehow convert missing reference to None, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mongoengine, the ReferenceField's `reverse_delete_rule` property can address situations where a document deletion leads to consistency issues.

The `reverse_delete_rule`'s `mongoengine.NULLIFY` attribute turns the fields referring to the deleted object to None.
This requires to drop the `null=False` declaration.

Your Event class would be amended like this:

```
class Event(Document):
    type = StringField(required=True)
    party= ReferenceField(
        Party, required=True,
        reverse_delete_rule=mongoengine.PULL
    )
```

You have two alternatives, depending on your design choices:

- `mongoengine.DENY` would prevent the deletion of the referenced object
- `mongoengine.CASCADE` would delete the documents associated with the referenced object as well as the referenced object.

The full list of attributes can be found in [this section of mongoengine's documentation](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#dealing-with-deletion-of-referred-documents).